# Dropping rows in dataframe if found in another one

Tags: python, pandas

There is one dataframe which is called all_combinations

```
Name      Store_Code Town   PostC   Revenue Street
 Starbucks   6890    Derby   post1   1       Street_1
 Starbucks   6891    Derby           0.5     NaN
 Starbucks   NaN     Derby   post6   NaN     Street_2
 Starbucks   6892    Derby   post2   0.9     Street_3
 Starbucks   6893    Derby   post3   2       Street_4
 McDonalds   6890    Derby   post1   1       Street_1
 McDonalds   8890    Derby   post4   2.8     Street_5
 McDonalds   8890    London  post5   1.7     Street_6
 McDonalds   NaN     London  post7   NaN     Street_7
 McDonalds   8888    London          2       Street_7
```

There is another dataframe which is called valid

```
Name      Store_Code Town   PostC   Revenue Street
 Starbucks   6890    Derby   post1   1       Street_1
 Starbucks   6891    Derby           0.5     NaN
 Starbucks   6892    Derby   post2   0.9     Street_3
 Starbucks   6893    Derby   post3   2       Street_4
 McDonalds   6890    Derby   post1   1       Street_1
 McDonalds   8890    Derby   post4   2.8     Street_5
 McDonalds   8890    London  post5   1.7     Street_6
```

Is there an **elegant** way that we can find the difference of rows between these two dataframes (in that case invalid) i.e

```
Name      Store_Code Town   PostC   Revenue Street
 Starbucks   NaN     Derby   post6   NaN     Street_2
 McDonalds   NaN     London  post7   NaN     Street_7
 McDonalds   8888    London          2       Street_7
```

Comment: Does the full row have to be the same? Or is only using `Store_Code` enough? (in the sense that for a certain Store_Code, the other columns are always the same)

Comment: The full row has to be the same. This is just an example of a use case, in the actual data there are 98 columns, so i created this data as a demonstration only

Comment: If you constructed an index that is a hash of the full row, you could simply do an (inner) join of the two data frames. Of course, building such an index might be too expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that elegant, but I think this should work: concat `all_combinations` and `valid`, and then drop all duplicates:

```
In [11]: all_valid = pd.concat([all_combinations, valid])

In [12]: all_valid[~(all_valid.duplicated() | all_valid.duplicated(take_last=True))]
Out[12]: 
        Name  Store    Town  PostC  Revenue    Street
2  Starbucks    NaN   Derby  post6      NaN  Street_2
8  McDonalds    NaN  London  post7      NaN  Street_7
9  McDonalds   8888  London    NaN        2  Street_7
```

The two times `.duplicated()` is to remove both first and second occurence of the duplicate.

The problem with using (a more elegant) `all_combinations[~all_combination.isin(valid).all()]` is that this also checks for equality of the index labels (which is not desired here I think).

Comment: Seems to me that this version can be slightly elegantified with 
`all_valid.loc[~(all_valid.duplicated(keep=False))]`

Answer (score 0):

yep. something like this should work:

```
invalid = set(all_combinations.Store_Code) - set(valid.Store_code)
all_combinations[all_combinations.Store_Code.isin(invalid) | (df.Store_Code.isnull())]
```

assuming that `Store_Code` is unique and that an `np.nan` `Store_Code` is invalid

using numpy functions:

```
invalid = np.setdiff1d(all_combinations.Store_Code, valid.Store_Code)
```